# SQL Query Split columns into multiple rows

Tags: sql, wordpress, split, pivot-table

This is most likely a duplicate in one way or the other. I viewed and tried many of the answers found. I am struggling with this for days, and I just can't get it working, or figure out how to apply some of the examples I found.

It seems most want to convert all columns into rows, which isn't what I want. What I probably need, as far as I can tell, is unpivot and/or UNION?

I am fetching Data from a WordPress table "wp_usermeta".

**WordPress Table Structure looks like:**

```
user_id | meta_key   | meta_value
1       | FirstnameA | Klaus
1       | SecondnameA| Reed
1       | FirstnameB | Herbert
1       | SecondnameB| Hall
2       | FirstnameA | Max
2       | SecondnameA| Musterman
....
```

**What I need:**

```
ID | Firstname_A | Lastname_A | Adress_A 

ID | Firstname_B | Lastname_B | Adress_B
```

Both rows would belong to the same ID.

**What my current Query looks like:**

```
SELECT user_id,

MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='firstnameA' THEN meta_value ELSE null END)  FirstnameA,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='lastnameA' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Lastname_A,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='adressA' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Adress_A,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='firstnameB' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) FirstnameB,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='lastnameB' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Lastname_B,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='adressB' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Adress_B

FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY user_id
```

**My result for this is:**

```
ID | Firstname_A | Lastname_A | Adress_A | Firstname_B | Lastname_B | Adress_B
```

MySQL-Version: 5.7

**My approch with JOIN for @janh also to show the actual meta_key:**

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;
select m1.user_id, m1.meta_value as Vorname_M, m2.meta_value as Nachname_M,m3.meta_value as Adresse_M,m4.meta_value as Telefon_M,m5.meta_value as Mail_M,
                   m6.meta_value as Vorname_V, m7.meta_value as Nachname_V,m8.meta_value as Adresse_V,m9.meta_value as Telefon_V,m10.meta_value as Mail_V,
                   m11.meta_value as Kinder, m12.meta_value as Kindergeburtstage,
                   m13.meta_value as Vorname_L, m14.meta_value as Nachname_L,m15.meta_value as Adresse_L,m16.meta_value as Telefon_L,m17.meta_value as Mail_L,
                   m18.meta_value as Arbeitskreise
from wp_usermeta m1
join wp_usermeta m2 on (m1.user_id = m2.user_id and m2.meta_key = 'nachnamemother')
join wp_usermeta m3 on (m2.user_id = m3.user_id and m3.meta_key = 'adress_mother')
join wp_usermeta m4 on (m3.user_id = m4.user_id and m4.meta_key = 'phone_mother')
join wp_usermeta m5 on (m4.user_id = m5.user_id and m5.meta_key = 'mail_mother')
join wp_usermeta m6 on (m5.user_id = m6.user_id and m6.meta_key = 'first_name_father')
join wp_usermeta m7 on (m6.user_id = m7.user_id and m7.meta_key = 'first_name_father_8')
join wp_usermeta m8 on (m7.user_id = m8.user_id and m8.meta_key = 'adress_father')
join wp_usermeta m9 on (m8.user_id = m9.user_id and m9.meta_key = 'phone_mother_16')
join wp_usermeta m10 on (m9.user_id = m10.user_id and m10.meta_key = 'mail_father')

join wp_usermeta m11 on (m10.user_id = m11.user_id and m11.meta_key = 'childs')
join wp_usermeta m12 on (m11.user_id = m12.user_id and m12.meta_key = 'birth_data')

join wp_usermeta m13 on (m12.user_id = m12.user_id and m13.meta_key = 'leben_vorname')
join wp_usermeta m14 on (m13.user_id = m13.user_id and m14.meta_key = 'leben_nachname')
join wp_usermeta m15 on (m14.user_id = m14.user_id and m15.meta_key = 'leben_adress')
join wp_usermeta m16 on (m15.user_id = m15.user_id and m16.meta_key = 'leben_phone')
join wp_usermeta m17 on (m16.user_id = m16.user_id and m17.meta_key = 'leben_mail')

join wp_usermeta m18 on (m17.user_id = m17.user_id and m18.meta_key = 'ak')

where m1.meta_key = 'firstnamemother'
```

---

**What worked for me:**

```
SELECT user_id,

CASE WHEN meta_key LIKE '%mother' THEN 'mother' 
     WHEN meta_key LIKE '%father' THEN 'father' 
     WHEN meta_key LIKE '%8' THEN 'father'
     END AS AorB,


MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='firstnamemother' 
           OR meta_key='first_name_father' 
         THEN meta_value END) AS Vorname,
        
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='nachnamemother' 
           OR meta_key='first_name_father_8' 
           THEN meta_value END) AS Nachname,
       
 MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='adress_mother' 
           OR meta_key='adress_father' 
           THEN meta_value END) AS Adresse
       
FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY
user_id,
CASE WHEN meta_key LIKE '%mother' THEN 'mother' 
     WHEN meta_key LIKE '%father' THEN 'father' 
     WHEN meta_key LIKE '%8' THEN 'father'
     END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit of the table and wanting A & B as rows not seperate columns you can change up your conditional aggregation slightly and add a new column to track whether a record is A or B.  Then group by it and your aggregations should give you want you want.

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,CASE WHEN user_key LIKE '%A' THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END AS AorB
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key LIKE 'first%' THEN meta_value END) AS FirstName
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key LIKE 'last%' OR meta_key LIKE 'sec%' THEN meta_value END) AS LastName
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key LIKE 'add%' THEN meta_value END) AS Address
FROM
    wp_usermeta
GROUP BY
    user_id
    ,CASE WHEN meta_key LIKE '%A' THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END
```

So you will need to only test for `firstname` not `firstnameb` because if you test for the entire string you will eliminate the A results and same is true for `lastname` and address.  Note when doing `case expression` if you don't include an `ELSE` everything that doesn't match a when statement will automatically be `NULL` so you can exclude that as well.

Per your comment you can add addition `OR` or `WHEN` statements in your `CASE` expressions even if not standard should be only x# of test cases.  Plus using `first%` instead of `firstname%` will account for 2 cases right away, or you might consider `f%`.  For last you can use `last%` and `sec%`, etc.

If you have a particular number of `firstnameA,B,C,D`.  you could also take `RIGHT(meta_key,1)` instead of a case expression just use the same thing in `group by`.  If you need more than 1 characters sometimes and not others that gets a little more difficult but you could mix depending on a case expression to test e.g. `CASE WHEN meta_key LIKE '%AB' THEN RIGHT(meta_key,2) ELSE RIGHT(meta_key,1) END`

Comment: Thank you. That actually looks awesome. Problem is, i didnt make the initial setup of this site, and the meta_keys (not user_key, sorry) arent actually that well organised. Its more like (firstname_A, secN), and a mess like that.Meaning the meta_keys are all complete different. But i will see if i can still apply this somehow. Also i corrected the Column names in my question.

Comment: @Lpion check my edits, I updated to account for your table structure change but also changed some case expressions to show you how to account for "fuzzy" standards.  and a potentially different way of dealing with N (secN).

Comment: Thank you. I am trying. I edited my question and added my JOIN approch, there can the real meta_keys be seen.

Comment: @Lpion yeah I was the upvote of the join approach and after clarification it isn't the right approach for what you are wanting to do.  Unfortunately with non standard data you are in for a little bit of a pain to determine values of meta_key and how to write your case expressions but you can do SELECT DISTINCT meta_key from wp_usermeta to see all of the values and determine how to do it.

Comment: Added small try to the question,to get the code right, and understand. The Problem is, it doesnt populate the "Vorname" column with the values, it is just NULL. What i am missing here ?

Comment: @Lpion your case expression is off it should be CASE WHEN meta_key LIKE 'firstname%' OR meta_key LIKE 'first_name_%' THEN END

Comment: @Lpion when doing OR you need to actually specify the full condition you can't just chain values

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. You explanation was very helpful. I updated my Question once more, with the query that works for me now. I hope its all correct.

Answer (score 2):

A `UNION ALL` will do the trick.

```
SELECT user_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='firstnameA' THEN meta_value ELSE null END)  FirstnameA,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='lastnameA' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Lastname_A,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='adressA' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Adress_A
FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='firstnameB' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) FirstnameB,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='lastnameB' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Lastname_B,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='adressB' THEN meta_value ELSE null END) Adress_B
FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Cant get it working, it gives me a syntax error for "user_id,". I did remove the comma after Adress_A, but still get the error.

Comment: @Lpion Fixed typo

Comment: @Matt I tried to add SELECT in the first place, before i saw the comma was too much after Adress_A, but then ii got:  Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list', even though on the first SELECT it doesnt seem to be a problem. I edited my Question, for the WP-Tablestructure

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a join should do it, shouldn't it?

Something like

```
select ID, pm_firstname.meta_value as firstname, pm_lastname.meta_value lastname, pm_address.meta_value as address FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_firstname ON (wp_posts.ID = pm_firstname.post_id AND pm_firstname.meta_key = 'firstname')
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_lastname ON (wp_posts.ID = pm_lastname.post_id AND pm_lastname.meta_key = 'lastname')
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_address ON (wp_posts.ID = pm_address.post_id AND pm_address.meta_key = 'address')
;
```

should get you the results nicely combined. Which type of join you'll need depends on your data and what should happen if a field doesn't exist for any post.

Comment: I worked with JOIN in the first place, problem is that it performs very bad.

Comment: I guess that depends on what exactly you did and how you did it, and what you consider bad performance. When you use WP_Query, to get/query meta fields in a query, it will use joins as well, and unless you're missing indexes, it works quite well.

Comment: Well the performance for about 5 lines was ok, but more then that and it wouldn't even show the result anymore, just loading forever.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. If you add your tries with joins to the question, I'm sure somebody can explain why they didn't perform.

Comment: Added my JOIN approch to my question.